# Traffic light Control on Arduino< looping

Tags: embedded, arduino-uno

The blinking part and the display is working properly except that it repeats for sometime and then stops. Please help me find out what's wrong. Is it a while loop problem or I did some mistakes in the timing part?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd( 12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2 ); //declaring the Lcd display pins

//pins declarations for each Leds
int red1 = 13;
int yellow1 = 10;
int green1 = 9;
int red2 = 8;
int yellow2 = 7;
int green2 = A4;
const long ti = 0;
unsigned long interval4 = 60000UL;
unsigned long interval1 = 9;
unsigned long interval2 = 6000UL;
unsigned long interval3 = 3000UL;

// setting
void setup()
{
    lcd.setCursor( 0, 0 );
    lcd.print( "\0" );
    lcd.setCursor( 0, 1 );
    lcd.print( "\0" );

    lcd.begin( 16, 2 );
    delay( 2000 );
    lcd.setCursor( 0, 0 );
    lcd.print( "HARIRI and JACOB\0" );
    lcd.setCursor( 0, 1 );
    lcd.print( "PROJECT\0" );
    delay( 3000 );
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor( 0, 0 );
    lcd.print( "traffic light\0" );
    lcd.setCursor( 0, 1 );
    lcd.print( "simulation\0" );
    delay( 2000 );
    lcd.clear();
    Serial.begin( 9600 );
    delay( 50 );
    pinMode( red1, OUTPUT );
    pinMode( red2, OUTPUT );
    pinMode( yellow1, OUTPUT );
    pinMode( yellow2, OUTPUT );
    pinMode( green1, OUTPUT );
    pinMode( green2, OUTPUT );
}

//the main loop
void loop()
{
    int ti = millis();

    while( (millis() - ti) < interval1 )
    {
        digitalWrite( red1, HIGH );
        {
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.setCursor( 0, 0 );
            lcd.print( "Way1: stop\0" );
            int ti = millis();

            while( (millis() - ti) < interval2 )
            {
                digitalWrite( green2, HIGH );
                lcd.setCursor( 0, 1 );
                lcd.print( "Way2: go\0" );
            }

            digitalWrite( green2, LOW );
            {
                ti = millis();
                while( (millis() - ti) < interval3 )
                {
                    digitalWrite( yellow2, HIGH );
                    lcd.setCursor( 0, 1 );
                    lcd.print( "Way2: wait\0" );
                }
                digitalWrite( yellow2, LOW );
            }
        }

        digitalWrite( red1, LOW );

        ti = millis();
        while( (millis() - ti) < interval1 )
        {
            digitalWrite( red2, HIGH );
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.setCursor( 0, 1 );
            lcd.print( "Way2: stop\0" );

            ti = millis();
            while( (millis() - ti) < interval2 )
            {
                digitalWrite( green1, HIGH );
                lcd.setCursor( 0, 0 );
                lcd.print( "Way1: go\0" );
            }

            digitalWrite( green1, LOW );

            while( (millis() - ti) < interval3 + interval2 )
            {
                digitalWrite( yellow1, HIGH );

                lcd.setCursor( 0, 0 );
                lcd.print( "Way1: wait\0" );
            }
            digitalWrite( yellow1, LOW );
        }

        digitalWrite( red2, LOW );

        ti = millis();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consistent and conventional indentation and whitespace aids readability and comprehensibility of you code.  This is especially important if you are asking others to review your code - don't make it unnecessarily difficult, otherwise no one will bother.  Your's was all over the place - I have fixed that for you.

Comment: In `loop()`, you have a braced (`{...}`)block with no control statement; this is valid but unusual ; it "localises" the second declaration of `int ti` -  it would be better to loose the block and declare a timer variable with a distinct name.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what the outer loop is for, but it breaks the Ardunio framework.

Your outer loop has an interval of 9 milliseconds, but the actions within the loop take much longer than that.  Further ti is updated at the end of the loop in any case, so the loop will never exist - breaking the Arduino framework which expects `loop()` to exist and calls it repeatedly.

It is generally best (or at least sympathetic to the Arduino framework) to implement `loop()` as a state-machine and not to have timing loops within it.  The state-machine switches state depending on time passed, but does not loop *waiting* for time to pass.